# FLASH AS3 - How to stop an external swf file

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, controls

I have this homepage, http://www.friedmanllp.com/home3.php, and two separate .swf files. I want the top .swf, the skip bar, to stop the bottom video. Is there anyway to do this?

Note I have no way to edit the original video. I wouldn't mind using a javascript solution but would rather target it with AS3 if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to use ExternalInterfaces to call your swf from outside (f.e. with javascript) but i guess that's what you meant with "no way to edit the original video".

what about a workaround like:
1 click the stop button and call a js function which
2 removes the video.swf from your page and
3 adds it again

best, kris

Comment: Yeah, that would work. I'd need the skip .swf file to stop the video and trigger the practices div (the orange boxes) as it does not upon completion.. Also, I'd like to have that mute button switch the audio on and off if at all possible.